# Pass column names dynamically to when condition to check is null condition on each column from a column list using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list containing column names ['id', 'label'] that can hold one or multiple values. I need to pass it to a when condition using withColumn to create another column populating values like delete in case any of the columns have null values, otherwise no delete.

Here's what I tried, but I got an issue, stating the col function accepts one argument.

```
Primary_key_columns = ['id', 'label']

df_new  = df_new.withColumn("action", when( col(*primary_key_columns).isNull(),"delete").otherwise("no delete") )

TypeError: col() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: you could use an OR condition for the check

Comment: problem here is, the list can be dynamic means can have 1 or n number of columns, so it needs to be dynamic basically check all the columns present in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create an OR condition chain dynamically using python's `reduce`.

here's an example

```py
null_chk_ls = map(lambda x: func.col(x).isNull(), primary_key_columns)
or_cond = reduce(lambda a, b: a|b, null_chk_ls)
# Column<'((id IS NULL) OR (label IS NULL))'>

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('action', 
               func.when(or_cond, func.lit('delete')).
               otherwise('no delete')
               ). \
    show()

# +----+-----+---------+
# |  id|label|   action|
# +----+-----+---------+
# |   1|  foo|no delete|
# |null|  bar|   delete|
# |   3| null|   delete|
# +----+-----+---------+
```